# Should the return value of a function be assigned to a variable even if the variable is not used?

Tags: python, software-design, readability

Just for example let's say I have a function to create an entry in a list, database, etc. and that function returns the id of that entry.  Should I always assign the return value of that function to a variable for readability, consistency, or later use, or should I just omit it since it's not being used?  Some code that may demonstrate my point is included below:

```
def add_to_list(val, arr):
    arr.append(val)
    return len(arr) - 1


def weird_function(val, arr):
    # print the index of the new element if the element is an odd number
    if val % 2:
        idx = add_to_list(val, arr)
        print(idx)
    else:
        add_to_list(val, arr)
        # idx = add_to_list(val, arr)
```

Should `idx =`  be included in the `else` statement for consistency's sake?

Comment: If you don't need it, why would you assign it?

Comment: No, it doesn't enhance readability if variables are set but never read. This is irritating.

Comment: In you particular example the control flow may be easier to follow to have: `idx = add_to_list(val, arr); if val % 2: print(idx)`

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I probably shouldn't have posed the sample code, since most people seem to just be keen on simplifying it, which is not the question I was asking.  I was just wondering other people's opinions on the matter since I've dealt with code that errs on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to store the value in `idx` variable if you're not going to use it anywhere. A better approach to improve the readability would be-

```
def add_to_list(val, arr):
    arr.append(val)

def weird_function(val, arr):
    # print the index of the new element if the element is an odd number
    if val % 2:
        print(len(arr))
    add_to_list(val, arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should `idx =`  be included in the else statement for consistency's sake?

It just depends on if you want to use `idx` later on. In your example you're not using, and so it need not be included.

There are cases, where you get a meaningful return value. For example you can have a file update function that will return true if a file was opened and written to successfully, else will return false. In such cases you might want to store the returned values into a log file or something.

Since you've asked this question, I assume you're fairly new to programming (or at least to Python), which means you might not really be working on anything "high end" at the moment. Therefore don't worry about saving anything.

The specific function you've written can be simplified to

```py
def weird_function(val, arr):
    if val % 2:
        print(add_to_list(val, arr))
    else:
        add_to_list(val, arr)
```

Comment: Don't assume too much!  I work with people who code both ways, so I was wondering about other people's opinions.